# Rails Data Modeling: Campaign Modeling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model, relational-database, database-schema

I am attempting to build out an ad network type application in rails that will allow for creating campaigns with the attributes similar here:
[image]

I wish for the user to be able to select multiple days, locations and time periods in the day for the campaign to run (as can be see in the image). Then the client, given their location, day of week and time period in the day will pull such an ad with those respective attributes.

I am aware that this is a complex model and building it efficiently is of critical importance. Are there perhaps tutorials or insights into how the model should be laid out?

Answer (score 0):

Store the schedule as an iCalendar [rrule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rrule?sort=votes) (or a more normalized version if your prefer).

Create a function to return upcoming dates for the rule.

Create a materialized view of upcoming dates if you need to, to boost performance.

[PostgreSQL Functions for RRULE handling](http://repo.or.cz/w/davical.git?a=blob;f=dba/rrule_functions.sql;hb=HEAD)

Use Table Inheritance to model the geographical locations. You should consider City to be a child of State and not County, as some cities *contain* counties.

You want to be able point a single foreign key at an abstract geographical location such as "Ohio" or "Cuyahoga County, Ohio"

Use a junction table to map multiple locations to a campaign.

```
--postgresql syntax

create table campaigns (
  campaign_id int primary key,
  name text unique,
  rrule text not null check ( is_valid_rrule(rrule) ) --you would need to write this
);

create table locations (
  location_id int primary key,
  type text not null check ( type in ('COUNTRY', 'PRIMARY_DIVISION','SECONDARY_DIVISION') ), --use a lookup table in real life
  name text not null,
  parent_id int null references locations (location_id) check ( type = 'COUNTRY' or parent_id is not null),

  unique (name, parent_id)
);

create table campaign_locations (
  campaign_id int references campaigns(campaign_id),
  location_id int references locations(location_id),

  primary key (campaign_id, location_id)
);

--insert some locations:

insert into locations values
(1, 'COUNTRY', 'United States of America', null),
(2, 'PRIMARY_DIVISION', 'Ohio', 1),
(3, 'SECONDARY_DIVISION', 'Cuyahoga County', 2),
(4, 'SECONDARY_DIVISION', 'Adams County', 2);

--create a campaign with a recurrence rule:

insert into campaigns values
(1, 'My Campaign', 'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE');

--associate a campaign with Cuyahoga and Adams counties:

insert into campaign_locations values
(1, 3),
(1, 4);
```